# Calling Array#delete_at on a cloned hash changes the original hash too?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

I ran into a bit of a strange issue, if I attempt to call `delete_at` on a cloned Hash which happens to have an array as one of it's key-values it will also delete from the original Hash. Is there any way of getting around this?

```
h1 = {:stuff => [1,2,3]}
h2 = h1.clone
h2[:stuff].delete_at(0)

puts h1 #=> {:stuff=>[2, 3]}
puts h2 #=> {:stuff=>[2, 3]}
```

Comment: Just for more clarification, I did this in irb and both array's had the same `object_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the array referred to as `h2[:stuff]` is identical to `h1[:stuff]`. You need to `dup` that.

```
h1 = {:stuff => [1,2,3]}
h2 = h1.clone
h2.keys.each{|k| h2[k] = h2[k].dup}
h2[:stuff].delete_at(0)
```

Or, more directly,

```
h1 = {:stuff => [1,2,3]}
h2 = {}
h1.each{|k, v| h2[k] = v.dup}
h2[:stuff].delete_at(0)
```

Note that immutable objects cannot be `dup`ed. In such case, you need to do something like:

```
h1 = {:stuff => [1,2,3]}
h2 = {}
h1.each{|k, v| h2[k] = v.dup rescue v}
h2[:stuff].delete_at(0)
```

Comment: Is this because `clone` makes a shallow copy?